# how do I install a previous version of meteor JS?

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to host a meteor app that uses an old version of meteor.
Every time i try to start the app it will get somewhat through the process of installing the tool, and then i see a message such as:

```
Killednloading meteor-tool@1.1.3...          -
```

(note how killed somehow overwrites the downloading part of the command line)

Is there a reliable way to install the meteor tool at a specific version?

Answer (score 59):

**EDIT:**

The Meteor team added a `release` parameter to their download endpoint. Now you can simply specify the desired version:

```
curl "https://install.meteor.com/?release=1.3.3.1" | sh
```

For Windows, a [`version` parameter](https://github.com/meteor/meteor-chocolatey-installer) exists for the `choco` installer:

```
choco install meteor --version 1.3.3.1
```

---

**Original solution**

You can use `sed` for that. Insert it in the middle of `curl` and `sh`:

```
curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sed 's/1.4/1.3.3.1/' | sh
```

That will replace the release 1.4 (current version) to 1.3.3.1

Comment: How about windows?

Comment: it serves only linux installation.

Comment: once you have proper release use this to block auto updates ... meteor --release x.y.z  some-command

Comment: I need to do this on windows, please suggest something

Comment: @DevAgrawal I've added a Windows solution which I found in the Chocolatey Installer guide.

Comment: This is no longer working! In Genuary 2019, the proper way is: meteor update --release x.y.z

Comment: @think01 I still see it working. The `meteor update` method works when going upwards to a release. But for a new installation, using the `release` HTTP parameter is the right solution. It is an uncommon use case, but when I figured this one out I was stuck in an environment which required a specific method upon installation.

Comment: @JorgeIssa you're right (it works for fresh new installations) but I wasn't able to use it to update an existing release. So they are mutually exclusive?

Answer (score 28):

When you create a meteor app you can specify a release:

```
meteor create test --release x.y.z
```

And when you *update* a meteor app you can do the same:

```
meteor update --release x.y.z
```

Answer (score 2):

@Jorge Issa's answer is good if you are installing Meteor from scratch, on a system that never had Meteor installed, however it's subject to change since versions change all the time, so you need to adapt the `sed` line.

If you have any version of Meteor already installed, as Michel Floyd mentioned, you can always create a project with a specific version by adding the `--release` flag.

`meteor update --release xxxx` works fine with you're actually upgrading, but downgrading is a different story.

My recommendation when it comes to upgrading and eventually downgrading, is to use version control (`git`).

Attempt upgrade and if all is fine, you're in good shape, if not and you want to downgrade, simply clear the file changes in your version control system and use `meteor reset` to clean your project and rebuild with the previous version.

**!Note! `meteor reset` clears the local mongo database too**, so be sure to back that up first if you're going to do that (check `mongodump` and `mongorestore` for that)

finally, if you're looking to clean up the clutter from the `.meteor` folder, you can delete the folder and then run `meteor reset` in your project: the meteor executable will detect you don't have the needed packages will re-download the packages for the version needed by your project. (This takes a while and if you have many project, can be cumbersome as you need to do this in each project, but if like me you are looking to clear some space, this works fine.)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
meteor update --release x.y.z
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: this is a perfectly good answer, and what's more it works. I don't agree with the comment above as no explanation is necessary.  However, the one thing to say is that this only works on an existing installation (obviously), but does a decent job of regressing for you. It is the SAME command whatever the platform, unlike the most rated answer which only works for linux ..

Comment: All these answers only work with existing meteor installations, but if you installed the latest version from scratch, or reinstalled the latest version, you don't have a previous version installed on your system, so you can't simple use `meteor update --release` or use git to roll back.

Comment: I had to do a `meteor reset` after that in order to make meteor works again.  Be AWARE that this command (the reset) will delete all the data in your local mongo database.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
choco install meteor --x86 --params="'/RELEASE:1.5.4.4'"
```