# `ReferenceError: Meteor is not defined` in `meteor-client.js` Angular-Meteor Project

Tags: angular-meteor

After an `npm install` which triggered `meteor-client bundle` during `postinstall`, I am receiving this new error in the browser console:

```
"ReferenceError: Meteor is not defined
    at Object.eval (webpack-internal:///../../../../meteor-client.js:32502:3)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///../../../../meteor-client.js:32507:30)
    at Object.../../../../meteor-client.js (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:1395:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:4200/inline.bundle.js:55:30)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///../../../../../clients/browser/main.ts:3:72)
    at Object.../../../../../clients/browser/main.ts (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:424:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:4200/inline.bundle.js:55:30)
    at Object.0 (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:439:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:4200/inline.bundle.js:55:30)
    at webpackJsonpCallback (http://localhost:4200/inline.bundle.js:26:23)"
```

```

Triggered at:

```
if (Package.reload) {
  Meteor._reload.onMigrate(function () {
    return [false];
  });
}
```

This behavior occurs with:

- `@angular/cli`: both 1.6.3 & 1.6.6
- `meteor-client-bundler`: 0.3.0
- `Meteor`: both 1.6.0.1 & 1.6.1

Answer (score 0):

Might be related to [this issue with a normal angular-meteor setup](https://github.com/Urigo/angular-meteor/issues/1855)? It seems like the Meteor version 1.6.0.1 is crashing the meteor-angular setup. I was testing both project setups, with and without AngularCLI, and experienced exactly the errors described here and at angular-meteor issues.

However, resetting the project to Meteor 1.6 worked for me in both cases.

Comment: Thanks. Upon your recommendation, I downgraded from 1.6.0.1 to 1.6 (1.6.0 does not technically exist) and then all the way back to 1.5.4.1) but am still encountering the same `Meteor is not defined` error in the browser console, so my issue appears to be something else.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and downgrade as John mentioned worked for me.

If you are wondering how to downgrade your meteor app follow the instructions bellow that I've taken from [how do I install a previous version of meteor JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36609525/how-do-i-install-a-previous-version-of-meteor-js)

```
1) Go to your project root folder
2) Run meteor update --release x.y.z
```

Where x.y.z is the desired version, for example 1.6.0

Comment: Just added more info about in my answer, and it supposed to be a comment instead of an answer. But as I don't  have enough reputation I left as an answer. I think is better to contribute with something instead of comment pointless subject as you did.