# Downgrade Meteor version

Tags: meteor, installation, version

I recently updated my Meteor version from 1.6 to 1.7, which seems to have unexpected bugs. In an attempt to fix them I reinstalled Meteor, which probably deleted old installations, which means I can't go back to 1.6. If I change the version in the `.meteor/release` file from `1.7` to `1.6.1.2`, it says that I need to update the release to `1.7`, which means I can't use the old version anymore. Is there any way I can install 1.6 version?
I'm using Windows 10 PC.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36609525/how-do-i-install-a-previous-version-of-meteor-js

Answer (score 1):

Are you tracking your project in version control?

The usual advice here is that you should make sure your app is committed to some VCS before starting the update so you can roll back. This works because Meteor uses the versions in `.meteor/release` and `.meteor/versions` to keep track of what to use to run your app.

> **Rolling back**
>
> In the unlikely event that the update leaves your application in a bad state, and you don’t feel like debugging it right away, please make sure your application’s `.meteor` directory is committed to your version control system (e.g. Git, Mercurial, etc.) before the update, so that it’s easy to revert the changes if you encounter problems.

If you don't have any version control, then my recommendation would be to update `.meteor/release` as you have tried, and also delete `.meteor/versions` and allow Meteor to pick versions again that are compatible with 1.6.1.2

Alternatively you could try creating a new project with Meteor 1.6.1.2, add the same package dependencies and copy over the `release` and `versions` files for the same set of packages.

```
$ meteor create 1612 --release=1.6.1.2
$ meteor add <packages from your app>
```

After you've copied them over, meteor should use version 1.6.1.2 and compatible dependency versions

Comment: As far as I know, the `versions` file is readonly, and any changes to it does not effect the project, as it is overwritten everytime I run meteor. So in a way I already tried you way. It would have worked, but as I said, when I reinstalled meteor, it deleted the old installations and installed only the latest release, so I can't roll back. I also tried creating a new project, but I get the same error that 1.6.1.2 is not installed and I need to use the 1.7 release.

Comment: If your `.meteor/release` file says 1.6.1.2 and you don't have that version installed, it will be automatically installed when you try to run any commands in that directory. Also Meteor uses the versions file to pick which versions to install and use for your app. By deleting it, you force Meteor to resolve the compatible dependencies again and select versions compatible with the current Meteor version and your current packages. It is *not* read-only, any changes there will tell Meteor to use that version. The file will only change when running `meteor update`

Comment: Well that's this thing... it doesn't install a previous version. If my release file says 1.6.1.2 and I only have 1.7 installed, then it asks me to update my release file instead of installing 1.6.1.2. It only works for upgrading, not downgrading.

Comment: It definitely works for me, so this might be a bug. You should add an issue on the meteor repo