# Install old meteorjs version

Tags: meteor

The Meteor docs and website explain how to install the latest version, with `curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh`or `npm install -g meteor`, but I need to install a particular old version. How can I install Meteor version 1.11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide a release parameter for example:

```
curl "https://install.meteor.com/?release=1.3.3.1" | sh
```

Also see:

[how do I install a previous version of meteor JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36609525/how-do-i-install-a-previous-version-of-meteor-js)

Answer (score 1):

You can always install the latest version and then use your project's version to boot the older version.

Meteor will respect your `.meteor/release` file, and if you need to create a project with a specific version you can use `meteor create --release 1.2.1 yourAppName`.